# How to compare 2 groups with different sizes?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, graph-theory

I wish to compare network density metrics.

I have 6 densities from 6 different graphs. Each graph has different number of nodes as well different number of edges.

I wanted to compare the 6 densities between the graphs. In doing this I divided the graph densities with number of nodes in the graph. For example a graph with a density of 0.55 was divided with 30 (number of edges in the graph). I did the same with the other 5 densities. Later I normalised the values and I represented on a bar chart. the chart suggests that graph densities decrease with number of nodes. Eg. high density scores are in graphs with low node scores.  I my understanding this would suggests the effect of density on graph size?

Is this calculation correct?